# Populate dropdown select elements with input value onchange using jQuery

Tags: jquery

i have input field
 `<input class="form-control" type="number" id="val-level" name="st_no" value="<?php echo $st_no; ?>" max="10" min="1" placeholder="How Many Levels..">`

And have Jquery function

```
$(document).ready(function() {
     var level_value = $("#val-level").val();

        $("#val-level").on("change",function(){
            level_value = $(this).val()

             var option = '';
            for (var i=0;i<level_value;i++){
option += '<option value="'+ level_value + '">' + level_value + '</option>';
                                        }
                $('#val-skill2').append(option);    
                });


 });
```

I want to populate option elements like 1,2,3 if I insert 3 on input field and when change to 2 populate 1,2. and so on

My dropdown

```
<select class="form-control" id="val-skill2" name="level">
        <option value="" selected disabled>Select Level</option>

      </select>
  <label for="val-skill2">Levels</label>
```

Comment: So whats the problem?

Comment: if when i input 3 it gives 3,3,3 instead of 1,2,3 and when change to let say 2 it append 3,3,3,2,2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- One of the problems what this line `option += '<option value="' +
  level_value  + '">' + level_value  + '</option>';` , It would always
  write the value of the input in every option, Use `i` instead.
- Another thing i did was to clear the select option when the input changed

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var level_value = $("#val-level").val();

  $("#val-level").on("change", function() {
    level_value = parseInt($(this).val())
$('#val-skill2 option').remove()
    var option = '';
    for (var i = 1; i < level_value +1; i++) {
      option += '<option value="' + i + '">' + i + '</option>';
    }
    $('#val-skill2').append(option);
  });


});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input class="form-control" type="number" id="val-level" name="st_no" value="" max="10" min="1" placeholder="How Many Levels..">

<select id="val-skill2"></select>
```

Comment: @japharyjuma Mark the answer if this is what you need.